# Error in getting JSON response from WSO2 DSS server where it contains a bit/boolean: "Error while writing to the output stream using JsonWriter"

Tags: json, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am getting the following error when I request a JSON response from WSO2 DSS service.

```
    {
  "Fault": {
    "faultcode": "soapenv:Server",
    "faultstring": "Error while writing to the output stream using JsonWriter",
    "detail": ""
  }
}
```

I noticed that this is happening when response contains a bit/boolean value. When I remove the latter the data is returned correctly in JSON.

Can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you are using very old DSS server. This issue has been fixed with latest [WSO2 DSS Server 3.5.0](http://wso2.com/products/data-services-server/)

Or As Workaround you can change the message formatters and builders in /repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file